# Proof that $U$ is an unitary operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-computer, unitarity

I have a function $f$ mapping a bit onto another bit, i.e. $f : \{0, 1\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\} $. The function *f* is either constant,
so *f*(0) = *f*(1) or balanced, so *f*(0) $\neq$ $f$(1). The quantum gate for the Deutsch algorithm is given below

[image: deutsch quantum gate]

The second gate *f* has the following form:

**$U_{f}$** : $|x,y \rangle$ $\rightarrow$ $|x, y$ $\oplus$ *f*(x) $\rangle$

where $\oplus$ is the exclusive-or operation. The *M*-gate performs a measurement of the qubits.

I have to prove that $U_f$ is an unitary operator.

**EDIT:** I know that an operator is unitary if the hermitian of the operator is the same as the inverse

$U_f ^{-1} = U_f ^\dagger$. And thought of comparing the results when applying both operators to $|x, y \rangle$

I am able to compute the hermitian of the operator when applied to $|x, y \rangle$, but I don't know how I could do this with the inverse

$U_f ^{-1} |x, y \rangle = ?$

Comment: Just apply $U_f^\dagger$ to $U_f| x,y \rangle$ and see if you get $| x,y \rangle$ back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ must be either constant or balanced, there are only 4 possibilities for what $f(x)$ could be. For each of these four cases, you can explicitly write $U_f$ as a matrix, which you can easily check for unitarity.